# proof of function being not continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show that the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, defined as $f(x)=0$ for $ x\notin \mathbb Q$ and  $f(x)=x$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$, is not continuous in all $x_0$  except for $x_0=0$.

My attempt: let $x_0\neq 0$.Set $\epsilon := x_0$. If $x_0 \in \mathbb Q$ then for all $\delta > 0 \ \  \exists x$ with $x \in \mathbb R \wedge x \notin \mathbb Q$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Hence we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|0-x_0|=x_0:=\epsilon$.

for $x_0 \notin \mathbb Q$ we have: for all $\delta>0 \ \ \exists x \in \mathbb Q$ with $|x| \geq x_0$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$, wich implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x-0|=|x|\geq x_0:=\epsilon$

the case with $x_0=0$ is easy to work out.

My question:

Is the proof correct or did I not understand the concept correctly?

If I'm wrong, are there some adjustments that can be done in  my proof without altering it entirely?

Comment: That looks fine to me. I would write it slightly differently to point out that what you do is to show that $\forall x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\exists \epsilon>0:\forall\delta>0\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-x_{0}|<\delta\land|f(x)-f(x_{0})|\geq\epsilon$. But the argument is correct.

Comment: Aside from some $x_0$ should be $|x_0|$, your proof looks okay to me.

Comment: thank you for your comments. @achillehui I was looking at your Icon, is the answer that it is both evil and good? (I can see angel's wings and a devil's tale?) or is the distinction between red and black important. Just curious.

Comment: That symbol is [eye of Horus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Horus#Mathematics) and the red and black does mean something. You can treat that as a puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_{0} \in \mathbb{Q}$ , $x_{0} \neq 0$ we can find a sequence $\{x_n{}\} \rightarrow x_{0}$, $x_{n} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n) = 0\neq x_{0} = f(x_{0})   $$

Similarly if $x_{0} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ , we can find a sequence $\{x_n{}\} \rightarrow x_{0}$, $x_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} x_n = x_{0} \neq f(x_{0}) = 0   $$

So in these two cases $f$ isn't continous.

Comment: nice approach but doesn't answer my question at all.